# Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with Nvidia 980M (x2) GPU

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Sager 9377 with dual NVIDIA 980M GPUs in SLI, and I am having some trouble setting up the CUDA aspect of them. I have the standard drivers installed and working with no problem at all, but I am unable to render anything using the CUDA technology. Each time I come up with the same results. When I restart the laptop, the resolution becomes all messed up to where the login screen is massively stretched out of the bounds of the laptop screen bounds, and when I log in, all I see is the background image of my desktop.

At this point, I am unable to open and use any programs to fix this. I have tried everything I can think of, from using various drivers, installing Boinc to enable the CUDA cores, and using the CUDA Toolkit, all to no avail. I did a fresh install each time. What is the best way to go from here?

I am also having trouble getting my optical drive to play DVDs and Blu-ray discs as well. I have all the proper drivers installed as well (as far as I know).

In case you need to know, here are my system's specs:

• Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
• Intel i7 4940MX
• 32GB Kingston RAM @ 1600 MHz.
• (x2) Samsung 840 EVO 1 TB SSD
• (x2) NVIDIA GTX 980M GPUs in SLI

I tried temporarily removing each one of the NVIDIA GTX 980M GPUs and using only the other one to check, and when I take out the primary GPU, the computer starts up and runs normally, but on just the one GPU. When I switched out to the other one in the GPUs and ran like it always does, but only on the main card with both showing up. When I ran on neither, the computer ran like normal, but the resolution was lowered from 1920x1080 to 1600x900. The main thing is I want to be able to render on my GPUs in Blender 3D, but I need to run that using the CUDA cores to be able to do that.

Comment: Anyone? No one knows?

Comment: I'm curious to know what would happen if, for troubleshooting purposes, you temporarily removed one of the two NVIDIA GTX 980M GPUs. For that matter, what would happen if you temporarily removed each one of the NVIDIA GTX 980M GPUs and used only the other one?

Comment: I just tried doing all that to check, and when I take out the primary gpu, the computer starts up and runs normally, but on just the one gpu. When I switched out to the other one in the other socket, it ran normally. When I took the SLI cable out, it picked up both gpus and ran like it always does, but only on the main card with both showing up. When I ran on neither, the computer ran like normal, but the resolution was lowered from 1920x1080 to 1600x900. The main thing is I want to be able to render on my GPUs in Blender 3D, but I need to run that using the CUDA cores to be able to do that.

Comment: (I am not familiar with a SLI setup, so some generic comments:) have you checked the (kernel) logs? Any detected hardware should show up there. Any UEFI/BIOS settings you can play with?

Comment: To add to the great comment by Lekensteyn, if there is anything in the UEFI/BIOS that needs to be changed if you have installed Linux, you don't always have to use the "trial and error" method. Check at your laptop manufacturer's forum webpage. You can sometimes find out which UEFI/BIOS setting needs to be changed at the manufacturer's forum.

Comment: Try the OEM driver http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/346.35/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.35.run